# Entity is saved in DB, but never gets fetched

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, seam

We're using JBoss Seam with JPA and Hibernate as persistence provider. We have encountered a very strange problem.
In our UI we have a tree. When we add a node to the tree, the node gets to postgres DB (the row is there, checked with pgadmin). But the tree is not changed. It appeared that named query (`OrganizationEntity.FIND_BY_ISDELETED_MAIN` below) that fetches nodes with their children, doesn't work correctly. The newly created object should appear under `OrganizationEntity.childOrganizations` - but it doesn't. `FetchType.EAGER` doesn't help, neither session flushing does.

What is the most ridiculous thing is that after about half an hour the query starts to return correct result! How come it happens? Is there any cache in hibernate that needs to be cleared or tweaked?

Thanks in advance!

UI tree:

```
<rich:tree id="OrgTrees" switchType="ajax" ignoreDupResponses="true">
            <rich:recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor
                roots="#{organizationServiceBean.getOrgTree()}" var="item"
                nodes="#{item.childOrganizations}"> 
                <rich:treeNode>
                    <a4j:commandLink value="#{item.fname}" ajaxSingle="true"
                        reRender="organizationViewForm,OrgTree"
                        onclick="this.disabled=true; if(g_flagChanges){if(confirm('Save changes?')){ updateCheck()} else{this.disabled=false;}}"
                        oncomplete="this.disabled=false; g_flagChanges=false;">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                            target="#{organizationBean4.selectedOrganization}"
                            value="#{item}" />
                        <a4j:support event="onclick" />
                    </a4j:commandLink>

                </rich:treeNode>
            </rich:recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor>
</rich:tree>
```

OrganizationServiceBean looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
@Name("organizationServiceBean")
public class OrganizationServiceBeanImpl implements OrganizationServiceBean, Serializable {
...
    public List<OrganizationEntity> getOrgTree() {
        return organizationService.findByIsDeletedMain(0);
    }

}
```

organizationService is the following:

```
@Stateless
@AutoCreate
@Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)
@Name("organizationService")
public class OrganizationServiceImpl extends
        GenericServiceImpl<OrganizationEntity> implements OrganizationService {
……
    public List<OrganizationEntity> findByIsDeletedMain(int isDeleted) {
        //entityManager.flush();
        List<OrganizationEntity> lOrg = findByCriteria(isDeleted, OrganizationEntity.FIND_BY_ISDELETED_MAIN);
        log.info("search finished...");
        return lOrg;
    }
….
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List<OrganizationEntity> findByCriteria(Object searchKey,
            String namedQuery) {

        final Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
        query.setParameter("searchKey", searchKey);
        List<OrganizationEntity> organizations = null;
        try {
            organizations = (List<OrganizationEntity>) query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } 
        return organizations;
    }
…..
}
```

And OrganizationEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "fname") })
@NamedQueries( {
….

        @NamedQuery(name = OrganizationEntity.FIND_BY_ISDELETED_MAIN, query = "select org from OrganizationEntity org where org.isdeleted = :searchKey and org.parentOrganization is null order by org.id", hints={@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable",value="false")}),
….})
@Name("organizationEntity")
public class OrganizationEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9085028098941577562L;

    ….
    public static final String FIND_BY_ISDELETED_MAIN = "OrganizationEntity.findByIsDeleted";
    ….
    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Organization
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private OrganizationEntity parentOrganization;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Organization
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentOrganization", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Where(clause="isdeleted = 0")
    private List<OrganizationEntity> childOrganizations;
}
```

---

**Edit**

The functionality works just fine if we cut conversation id from url - which means that

```
http://localhost:8080/h2p2/admin/admin.seam?cid=7
```

doesn't work no matter how many times we refresh it, but

```
http://localhost:8080/h2p2/admin/admin.seam
```

works fine.

Comment: Have you checked transaction handling and caches?

Comment: Only to make sure what you problem is: You set the isDeleted Flag for one (child) organisation, and it stayes in the parent organisation. - Is this correct?

Comment: Do I get it right that you call EJB directly from jsf page without faces backing beans?

Comment: @Ralph: We add child organization to parent organization, and we can't see the child. However, if we add root organization (whose parent_id == null), it gets displayed correctly

Comment: @Osw: Yes. That's because we're using seam, and it allows to eliminate backing beans from jsf

Comment: @denisk, I'd suggest to narrow the problem by instantiating new EntityManager from EntityManagerFactory within your findByIsDeletedMain(int isDeleted)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you have a 2nd level cache that's caching the objects retrieved from the query (the query itself is marked as cacheable=false but hibernate could still consult the cache when realizing the objects). You can either evict the parent object from the 2nd level cache after the update (on every server that may have that entity cached) or have the entity manager used in the query ignore the cache.

To do the latter, do the following before you issue the query:

```
entityManager.setProperty("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetreiveMode.BYPASS);
```

That effectively disables consulting the cache for that query and could be performance concern.

Comment: I am not sure that this works, because the relation ship is maintend by the changed object.

Comment: That's nice one, unfortunately it didn't help... Are there any other ways of disabling second level cache?

Comment: @denik: did you checked that the problem is gone away if you compleatly deactivate the second level cache?

Comment: @Ralph: No, disabling the second level cache entirely doesn't affect the problem...

Comment: I have discovered that seam conversation ID causes the issue - see my edit